$\operatorname {Jac}(C)[n]\cong (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{2g}$
Let $C$ be an algebraic curve of genus $g$ over the field $\mathbb{F}_q$, with $q=p^r$, and  $p$ prime. If $\gcd(p,n)=1$, then $\operatorname {Jac}(C)[n]\cong (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{2g}$.
I am self-studying hyperelliptic curves from the book handbook of elliptic and hyperelliptic curve cryptography, Discrete mathematics and its applications. Kenneth Rosen.
And This is the Theorem 14.11, but there is not proof and any reference, but i don't know how to start to prove it, any hint or reference of a elemental proof?.

Strictly speaking, it depends on what we mean by "points" since we shouldn't expect there to be rational torsion points for any $n$ since the $\mathbb{F}_q$-points of a finite-dimensional variety are always finite.
As such, let's work over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$. In this case, Theorem 3.2.23 of these notes proves that if $n$ is coprime to $p$, then the multiplication by $n$ map is finite and étale of degree $n^{2g}$. In particular, the preimage of the identity (ie. the $n$-torsion subgroup) consists of $n^{2g}$ points. But then, the only finite abelian group of order $n^{2g}$, which has exactly $m^{2g}$ points which are $m$-torsion, for every divisor $m$ of $n$, is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^{2g}$.
Since these are finitely many points over the algebraic closure, they are all defined over a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$, so you can always base change to a slightly larger finite field to ensure that you have this torsion rational subgroup. However, if you're okay with allowing points of degree $> 1$, then no base-change is necessary.
